# Передача параметров в функцию BitConverter.ToUInt32

Tags: c#

Очень глупый, скорее всего, вопрос.

```
using System;
namespace example
{
    class Prog
    {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
             byte[] bytes = new byte[] {53, 0};
             uint sd = 0;

             sd = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes,0);

          }
    }
}
```

выполняя этот код, получаю исключение.
[image: исключение BitConverter.ToUInt32()].

Не могу понять, в чём дело, ведь вроде все аргументы я передаю правильно.

Comment: ToUInt32 ожидает массив минимум из 4 байт

Comment: Нда, оказывается, 4 байта надо. Спасибо!